# What is the best practice to send AJAX requests in Wordpress for plugin developers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

We're developing an Wordpress plugin, and for that we need to send some AJAX requests in the admin side across files **within our own plugin directory**. Currently it is working fine if I send it directly to that specific file url, like-

`$.get("https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sample_projects&action=delete&id=01&noheader=true", function(status){`
`//Do something here });`

But I'm reading everywhere in the community that to use AJAX in Wordpress I need to direct requests to admin-ajax.php. I found a good documentation here- https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

So, my questions are-

1. What problems may I face if I send the requests directly to this file?
2. If I need to send it to admin-ajax.php, where do I include my javascript and PHP codes?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this question seems repetitive to you.

Comment: 1) Apart from what technical issues that might cause, your plugin might simply be rejected from being listed in any official plugin directory.

Comment: 2) Explained right there in the document you referred to: _"Then, set up a PHP function to handle the AJAX request."_ So this `add_action` call and your function must be located somewhere in your plugin file, usually the `add_action` would go into some sort if initialization function.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the comment. But I want to fire this request inside a conditional if statement. Then which WP `add_action` I hook my javascript into(e.g. in that documentation they've hooked into 'admin_footer')? Now I just put it inside the 'if' condition.

Comment: What condition? Determined on the server or on the client side?

Comment: @CBroe Client side. Basically I want to pick up an 'window.closed' event with javascript, and if it is met, then fire this AJAX request.

Comment: So why does it matter _where_ exactly the JS code gets put then?